# Different servlet versions web apps on one App Server

Tags: java, tomcat

Please help me. I have an old Servlet 2.5 application with JSF 1.2 and tomcat 6.0.14
I need to move it to JSF 2.2 and tomcat 8 but changing all pages and controllers is impossible. Is there a way to run 2 apps at the same time? One app is growing and another is old. I know about nginx solution but may be there's a way to run both apps in one container? What would you suggest the best? Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking?, for me at least is not quite clear.

Comment: You want to deploy 2 apps in one container (tomcat), but one app is using tomcat 6 and the other is tomcat 8? Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Sorry, let me explain more clearly. I have an old app that has been developed for 10 years. It uses Struts 1, JSF 1.2,etc. Ideally, I`d like to rewrite the entire app for the most modern frameworks and run under the latest tomcat. But migration is not possible. So I need to implement solution when old app running as it is, and new ap is growing as quick, as I have some time for that. So for example this week I finished to refactor certain old app`s feature with JSF 2.2 fe, and tomorrow morning all requests to old app feature go to new refactored one. I dont like nginx. Thank you

Comment: Understandable but you probably are switching too early to JSF 2.2. Try prepare the switch in the old system. Start with a list of all sources to tackle, say in Excel or google spreadsheet, and use percentages done by date/file. So you can document the progress through time. Probably you'll need to make a translation tool (replaces). Until very late leave the old system running on the development systems too. Such a rewrite/migration may take long, and best would be a small prototype ported from old to new.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Your vision is the only correct but impossible for me. I and some others devs every day changing old system and I will have to follow all their commits in new system. Its impossible and I really have no time for that. So the only way is have old live and new growing systems. The only way I can see now is have a table, insert record with session info before redirect to new system and read record in new system to check validity. I cant see any other solution as I am going to use 2 different tomcats (6 and 8). Thank you